# ‘Web Sharing’ won't turn off

Tags: macos, sharing

I'm trying to turn off the **Web Sharing** service from the Preferences panel, but everything I try, it just gets stuck on ‘Interrupting...’, with an orange icon, and it doesn't do anything. If I close the Preferences panel and come back, I find it turned on again.

(I reckon that it's not stopping due to the missing `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`, because when I try to stop it using the terminal, with `sudo apachectl stop`, I get an error that says that it can't find that file)

What could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix it was to reinstall OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist?  If so, either replace it with a copy from another Mac (so it can be disabled properly), or reboot the computer (since it doesn't exist, it won't get loaded on reboot).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `sudo killall httpd`? I'd also check Console to see if there's any errors.

Comment: It kills just my own Apache server (installed separately) but not the built-in one! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing launch daemons from your /System/ folder, the best long-term solution is to perform an Archive and Install so that you keep your content and simply rebuild your damaged operating system.